# Why does debounce code not work with 2 or more objects?

Tags: c++, oop, arduino

I have written a debounce class to debounce inputs.

The idea was that a state of a certain input may be ON, OFF, FALLING or RISING.
the object.debounceInputs() is to be called with a fixed interval

With the the function object.readInput() the correct state of the object could be read in. A FALLING or RISING state only lasts for 1 interval time (usually set at 20ms) and these states can only be read once.

Ofcourse I tested the software and it worked without flaw, now I started using the software in other projects and a peculiar bug came to light.

The software works perfectly fine... if you have just one input object. If you debounce more than 1 object, the inputs are affecting each other which should not be possible as every object uses private variables.

The source code:

```
#include "debounceClass.h"
Debounce::Debounce(unsigned char _pin) {
    pinMode(_pin, INPUT_PULLUP); // take note I use a pull-up resistor by default
    pin = _pin; 
}

unsigned char Debounce::readInput() {
    byte retValue = state;

    if(state == RISING)  state = ON; // take note I use a pull-up resistor
    if(state == FALLING) state = OFF;  // rising or falling may be returned only once

    return retValue; 
}

void Debounce::debounceInputs() {
    static bool oldSample = false, statePrev = false;
    bool newSample = digitalRead(pin);

    if(newSample == oldSample) {    // if the same state is detected atleast twice in 20ms...
    
        if(newSample != statePrev) { // if a flank change occured return RISING or FALLING
            statePrev = newSample ;

            if(newSample)   state = RISING; 
            else            state = FALLING;
        }

        else {                      // or if there is no flank change return PRESSED or RELEASED
            if(newSample)   state = ON; 
            else            state = OFF;
        }
    }

    oldSample = newSample;
    return 255;
}
```

The corresponding header file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#ifndef button_h
#define button_h

//#define 
#define ON 9 // random numbers, RISING and FALLING are already defined in Arduino.h
#define OFF 10

class Debounce {
public:
    Debounce(unsigned char _pin);
    unsigned char readInput();
    void debounceInputs();

private:
    unsigned char state;
    unsigned char pin; 
};
    
#endif
```

I have had this bug with 2 separate projects, so the fault definitely lies in my Debounce class.

An example program to illustrate the program:

```
#include "debounceClass.h"

const int pin3 = 3 ;
const int pin4 = 4 ;

Debounce obj1( pin3 ) ; 
Debounce obj2( pin4 ) ;

byte previousState1, previousState2;
unsigned long prevTime = 0, prevTime1 = 0, prevTime2 = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin( 115200 ) ;
    // CONSTRUCTOR OF OBJECTS SETS THE PINMODE TO INPUT_PULLUP
    pinMode( pin3, OUTPUT ) ;
    pinMode( pin4, OUTPUT ) ;
}

const int interval = 20, interval1 = 1000, interval2 = 2000;

void loop() {
    unsigned long currTime = millis() ;

    if( currTime > prevTime + interval ) {
        prevTime = currTime ;

        obj1.debounceInputs();  // comment one of these 2 out, and the other debounces perfectly
        obj2.debounceInputs();

        #define printState(x) case x: Serial.print(#x); break

        byte state = obj1.readInput() ;

        if( state != previousState1 ) {
            previousState1 = state ;
            
            Serial.print("state of obj1 = ") ;
            switch ( state ) {
                printState( ON ) ;
                printState( OFF ) ;
                printState( RISING ) ;
                printState( FALLING ) ;
            }
            Serial.println();
        }
    
        state = obj2.readInput() ;

        if( state != previousState2 ) {
            previousState2 = state ;
            Serial.print("state of obj2 = ") ;
            switch ( state ) {
                printState( ON ) ;
                printState( OFF ) ;
                printState( RISING ) ;
                printState( FALLING ) ;
            }
            Serial.println();
        }
    }

    if( currTime > prevTime1 + interval1 ) {
        prevTime1 = currTime ;
        digitalWrite( pin3, !digitalRead( pin3 ) );
    }

    if( currTime > prevTime2 + interval2 ) {
        prevTime2 = currTime ;
        digitalWrite( pin4, !digitalRead( pin4 ) );
    }
}
```

This program automatically toggles both pins so you do not need physical inputs. If you comment out one of the indicated lines, you'll see that the other pin is debounced just fine. But when both pins are debounced the result is catastrophic. There is a weird link between the 2 objects which I cannot explain. I have reached a point at which I start doubting the compiler, so that was the moment I realized that I need to ask others.

Why is this happening and what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I cannot use a static variable within a class method. These static variables are seen by all objects which caused the problem.

I moved the static variables to the private variable section